# Django не видит картинок из статик папки

Tags: django

Добрый день!

Имеется `macOS Sierrа`, использую старый проект ( создавался на `Linux` и, быть может, проблема в этом ) 
У меня имелась папка `static` в которой лежали файлы для приложения `landing`. Они были разбросаны по всей папке, но работали. Т.к создалось еще одно приложение, в эту папку было неудобно помещать файлы для двух приложений с одним названием, поэтому я в ней сделал папку под названием `landing` и кинул туда все статик файлы. Получился путь => `projectname/static/landing/`

в `html` файле редактировал правильный путь, но при запуске выдает ошибку:

`GET /static/landing/img/397x300/03.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1691`

вот мой конфиг файл:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TAMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
MEDIA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_DIR
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Использую Джанго последней доступной версии

Comment: `'django.contrib.staticfiles'` в INSTALLED_APPS включен?

Comment: @FeroxTL Да, включен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
```

добавь в конце файла

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
                          document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```